# Validation Rule Help Please

Tags: validation-rule

BMCServiceDesk__Queue__c = **The Queue**

BMCServiceDesk__FKOpenBy__c = **The Staff**

**____________________________________________**

**A.** I'm trying to make it where, it does not allow Staff assignment without Queue assignment.

This works for that:

```
ISBlank(BMCServiceDesk__Queue__c ) && 
NOT(ISBLANK( BMCServiceDesk__FKOpenBy__c))
```

[image]
[image]

**B.** But they also want... To be able to save it if No Queue Or Staff is assigned... & "**A.**" prohibits that.:

[image]
[image]

So I built this (instead), but it's not working because it's overriding "**A.**"
(Same Validation Rule, Different Syntax)

```
ISBlank(BMCServiceDesk__Queue__c ) && 
NOT(ISBLANK( BMCServiceDesk__FKOpenBy__c)
 ||  
ISBLANK(BMCServiceDesk__Queue__c ) &&
ISBLANK(BMCServiceDesk__FKOpenBy__c))
```

What am I doing wrong and/or is this even possible?

Comment: Will, You explain your scenario briefly. In both cases what they are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a second rule. If queue is blank and staff is blank, then rule A won't trigger. In either case, your second version is wrong because validation rules trigger when the result is true, which it would be queue and staff are both blank. There's really no need to specify this as a rule.

Comment: Rule A, causes the error if both Staff and Queue are blank.

Comment: @Tim It shouldn't; it's likely you're doing something wrong. It will only fire exactly when queue is blank and staff is not.